# Compress/Decompress based on probability

Tags: encoding, compression, entropy

I am currently reading [Fundamentals of Multimedia](http://books.google.com/books/about/Fundamentals_of_Multimedia.html?id=cIxQAAAAMAAJ) by Ze-Nian Li

In the book there is a sample problem which I can't quiet solve, even though I seem to understand entropy and arithmetic encoding/decoding.

Given a data stream that has been compressed to a length of 100,000 bits, and told that it is the result of running an “ideal” entropy coder on a sequence of data. You are also told that the
original data consists of samples of a continuous waveform, quantized to 2 bits per sample. The probabilities of the uncompressed values are as follows:

```
00 - 8/16
01 - 6/16
10 - 1/16
11 - 1/16
```

How would I figure out the approximate length of the uncompressed signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you "seem to understand entropy", you can simply use the formula for entropy to do your homework.  Here is a hint from Boltzmann's tombstone:

[image: S = k log W]